# C # GetProperty does not work

Tags: c#

```
public interface IBase { }

public class Base<T> : IBase
{
    public static string GenericName { get { return typeof( T ).Name; } }
}

public class A : Base<int> { }
public class B : Base<float> { }
public class C : Base<string> { }

class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        Type findType = typeof( IBase );
        Type[] types = ( from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                         from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                         where findType.IsAssignableFrom( assemblyType )
                         select assemblyType ).ToArray();

        // i = 2 is class A
        for( int i = 2; i < types.Length; i++ )
        {
            Type type = types[i];
            PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty( "GenericName", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static );

            if( null != propertyInfo ) // propertyInfo is NULL!
            {
                string getType = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue( null, null );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

We have implemented GetType of Base  to check the type of A, B, C, but we can not call it.
Why is the result of GetProperty null?
And are there any solutions to these problems?

Comment: Well, after fixing the compile errors in your code and running it, it actually appears to be working for some of the types in your `types` array.  However, I got a different error message on the line inside the `if` statement: *Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true.*

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm sorry, the code I asked was written to simplify the code I have now, and I did not check it was working.
The problem with the code has been fixed once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Type findType = typeof(IBase);
            Type[] types = (from domainAssembly in AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
                            from assemblyType in domainAssembly.GetTypes()
                            where findType.IsAssignableFrom(assemblyType)
                            select assemblyType).ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < types.Length; i++)
            {
                PropertyInfo propertyInfo = types[i].GetProperty("GetType",  BindingFlags.Static| BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy| BindingFlags.Public);

                if (null != propertyInfo) // propertyInfo is NULL!
                {
                    string getType = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Now in your code , you wanted to get the value of property using GetValue() as
 
string getType = (string)propertyInfo.GetValue(null, null);

but unfortunately it throws exception "OperationException"
Exception Message as
"Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true"

Comment: thanks very much, well solved.